# Keeping database session open

Tags: scala, slick

I am trying to leverage `TypeSafe`'s slick library to interface with a MySQL server. All the gettingstarted/tutorial examples use `withSession{}` where the framework will automatically create a session, execute the queries within the `{}`'s, then terminate the session at the end of the block.

My program is rather chatty, and I would like to maintain a persistent connection throughout the execution of the script. So far I have pieced together this code to explicitly create and close sessions.

```
val db = Database.forURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost/sandbox", user = "root", password="***", driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
val s = db.createSession()
...
s.close()
```

Where I can execute queries in between. However, when I try to execute a command, such as

> (Q.u + "insert into TEST (name) values('"+name+"')").execute

It crashes because it cannot find the implicit session. I don't completely understand the [syntax of the execute definition in the documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.0/api/#scala.slick.jdbc.StaticQuery), but it seems like there might be an optional parameter to pass an explicit session. I've tried using .execute(s), but that spits out a warning that (s) doesn't do anything in a pure expession.

How do I explicitly specify a pre-existing session to run a query on?

**Appended:** Trial code for JAB's solution

```
class ActorMinion(name: String) extends Actor
{
    Database.forURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost/sandbox", user = "root", password="****", driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") withSession
    {
        def receive =
        {
            case Execute =>
            {
                (Q.u + "insert into TEST (name) values('"+name+"')").execute

                sender ! DoneExecuting(name,output,err.toString)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which returns compile error

> [error] /home/ubuntu/helloworld/src/main/scala/hw.scala:41: missing parameter type for expanded function
>
> [error] The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
>
> [error] Expected type was: ?
>
> [error]                 {
>
> [error]                 ^
>
> [error] one error found

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able derive what I needed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758228/how-can-i-remove-codes-creating-session-in-unit-test-for-play-framework-and-slic/16763350#16763350)

```
//imports at top of file
//import Database.threadLocalSession <--this should be commented/removed
import scala.slick.session.Session // <-- this should be added
......
//These two lines in actor constructor
val db = Database.forURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost/sandbox", user = "root", password="****", driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
implicit var session: Session = db.createSession()
......
session.close() //This line in actor destructor
```

Answer (score 2):

Just enclose the relevant part of your script in `withSession{}`. Note that if you are keeping the session open for a while/are performing lots of database manipulation queries, you should also look into taking advantage of transactions.

And you should really be using prepared statements for inserts if the data has a potentially external source.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for my implimentation. I have an actor receiving messages that I then want recorded in the database. The messages are received asynchronously coming in over the receive() interface. I tried wrapping the withSession{} around the receive() definition, but scala does not like me making definitions inside an anonymous function.

Comment: Also, yes I am intending to tackle transactions/prepared statements next, after I can get a working PoC for my sessions setup using a basic query. :)

Comment: What doesn't Scala like about it? Admittedly I haven't worked with concurrency in context managers that much, but I don't see why a definition inside an anonymous function would be any different from a definition inside a named function. Perhaps there's another issue involved?

Comment: I posted the code I used to test what you suggested, along with the error it spit back. Its very possible I implemented it incorrectly as I am still very much new to scala. Its also possible that this is the more correct way to do this and what I posted is more of a hack than correct form. As far as the error returned, it is my guess that the receive() method is supposed to override the inherited receive() in the extended Actor class. By being inside of the withSession block, I'm guessing this does not override correctly.

Comment: I think the issue is more that you have `receive()` wrapped in the block, but not the class itself and any uses of it (I'm fairly new to Scala myself, but trying to use a persistent context manager within a class instead of having the class and any instances of it within the manager doesn't seem right, though that may only be due to my Python background). Try wrapping the entire class definition, plus any instances of the class and uses of those instances, within the call to `withSession`. If that still gives an error, the issue would then be due to the limitations of Scala type inference.

Comment: http://pchiusano.blogspot.com/2011/05/making-most-of-scalas-extremely-limited.html As an aside, you might want to put your opening braces on the same line as the preceding code; the way Scala handles implicit semicolons/statement termination at newlines apparently has similar ambiguity issues to those in JavaScript. http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/nested-blocks.html (Personally, I prefer putting braces on a new line as well, but in this case it seems like a necessary evil.)

Comment: I played around with a few different configs. If I wrap the Database withSession() call around the entire script, the compiler complains about the call not being a class definition. If I nest it inside the main object (script entry point) then other classes complain about not being able to see the embedded actor definition inside. I will probably play with some more configurations down the road as I begin understand scala's scoping better, and report anything I find back here.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the {} styling. A bummer for sure its not supported, but knowing that now will be a lot easier to adjust and save me from hanging myself at some point down the road.